# TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: json, python-3.x

Hi i have a problem with my code that i get a error in a loop that works for a few times but then throws me a typeerro: string indices must be integers.
I want to call an api to get a json back and get some parts of the json response. heres the code:

```
class API(object):

    def __init__(self, api_key):
        self.api_key = api_key


    def _request(self, api_url, params={}):
        args = {'api_key': self.api_key}
        for key,  value in params.items():
            if key not in args:
                args[key] = value
        response = requests.get(
            Consts.URL['base'].format(
                url=api_url
                ),
            params=args
            )
        if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            return response.json()
        else:
            return "not possible"               
        print(response.url)


    def get_list(self):
        excel = EXCEL('s6.xlsx')
        api_url = Consts.URL['list'].format(
            version = Consts.API_VERSIONS['matchversion'],
            start = excel.get_gamenr()
            )
        return self._request(api_url)


    def get_match(self, matchid):
        idlist = matchid
        api_url  = Consts.URL['match'].format(
            version = Consts.API_VERSIONS['matchversion'],
            matchId = idlist
            )
        return self._request(api_url)


    def match_ids(self):
        api = API('c6ea2f68-7ed6-40fa-9b99-fd591c55c05f')
        x = api.get_list()    
        y = x['matches']
        count = len(y) 
        ids = []
        while count > 0:
            count = count - 1
            temp = y[0]
            ids.append(temp['matchId'])
            del y[0]

        return ids

    def match_info(self):
        matchids = self.match_ids()
        print(matchids)
        matchinfolist = {}
        counter = 1
        for gameids in matchids:
            info = self.get_match(gameids)
            myid = self.find_partid(info['participantIdentities'])
            prepdstats = info['participants'][myid-1]
            print(prepdstats)
            matchinfolist['stats' + str(counter)] = prepdstats
        return matchinfolist


    def find_partid(self, partlist):
        partid = 0
        idlist = partlist
        while partid < 10:
            partid = partid + 1
            tempplayer = idlist[0]['player']
            if tempplayer['summonerId'] == 19204660:
                playernr = partid
                partid = 500

            del idlist[0]

        return playernr
```

when i run the match_info() function i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Niklas\Desktop\python riot\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Niklas\Desktop\python riot\main.py", line 10, in main
    print(api.match_info())
  File "C:\Users\Niklas\Desktop\python riot\api.py", line 78, in match_info
    myid = self.find_partid(info['participantIdentities'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

but only after the loop in the function has run for a few times. I have no idea what im doing wrong. Any help would be nice.

Here is a link to the json: https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.2/match/2492271473?api_key=c6ea2f68-7ed6-40fa-9b99-fd591c55c05f

Answer (score 0):

The error shows up on

```
            myid = self.find_partid(info['participantIdentities'])
```

For this line to execute, info must be a mapping with string keys, not a string itself.  `info` is

```
            info = self.get_match(gameids)
```

`get_match` ends with

```
        return self._request(api_url)
```

`_request` ends with

```
        if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            return response.json()
        else:
            return "not possible"
```

For the loop to ever run, `response.json()` must be a dict with key `'participantIdentities'`.  Your bug is expecting that to always be true.

One fix might be to make the expectation always ture.  If there is a satisfactory default value, return `{'participantIdentities': <default value>}`. Otherwise, return `None` and change the loop to

```
            info = self.get_match(gameids)
            if info is not None:
                # as before
            else:
                # whatever default action you want
```